# How declarations works in memory

Tags: c++, memory, allocation

Let's assume that two variables:

```
  int x = 10;
  float y = 10.5;
```

both have 4 bytes allocated in memory,
but how this works, since operations with int and float are different?

Following the same logic:

```
  Animal * d = new Dog ();
```

Animal is a pointer that points to a dog, but a pointer is 4 bytes and stores an address. How he knows he is an animal? So later you can do d.sound();

Comment: The short answer is that the compiler knows which type you've declared, and treats the variable according to that type (e.g. generating integer instructions for `int` variables and floating-point instructions for `float` variables). The long answer would fill a book.

Comment: This is covered in any decent C++ book or reference site. You should find one; Google and Bing are both excellent at searching for web sites, and places like Amazon allow you to search for books on a topic and even sort the results by reviewer ratings. (Short answer: The compiler is designed to understand the code and make the proper allocations and associations.)

Comment: I mean, the ability to do this is pretty much the main purpose of compilers.

Comment: That book being similar to the "Dragon Book". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools#Second_edition

Comment: `both have 4 bytes allocated in memory` / `but a pointer is 4 bytes` not necessarily, never make assumptions about the size of fundamental types.

Comment: @user657267 I know, it was just for the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration tells the compiler two things:

1. How much memory to allocate for the variable.
2. What kind of code to generate when performing calculations using the variable.

So when you use an expression like `x + 6`, the compiler will emit code that makes use of the integer addition instruction of the CPU. When you use `y + 6`, it will emit code that makes use of the floating point addition instruction.

Type declarations are also use to determine when to convert values if you call a function that expects a different type than the variable, or perform assignments between variables of different types. E.g. if you have

```
void floatfun(float z);
```

and you call `floatfun(x)`, the compiler will generate code that computes the floating point equivalent of `x`'s value, and pass that to the function.

When the type is a struct or class, the declaration further allows the compiler to determine which members can be used, and how to translate member names to code that accesses them. The compiler also knows about the relationship between base classes and derived classes, so it knows that you can assign `Dog*` to `Animal*`, and performs the appropriate transformations (in C++ this involves a data structure called the *vtable*).